# subl: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git-bash

I'm a newbie trying to train my self using ruby on rails. I am trying to follow an instruction where I am require to type in "subl Gemfile" on Git Bash but it constantly keeps showing 'sh.exe": subl: command not found'. Kindly advice the way forward. 
P/S: I am a beginner in programming

Comment: I assume that is to open the Gemfile in sublime text.  Are you using sublime text?

Answer (score 0):

go to the directory where you're creating your RoR app. 
suppose you're creating your app at

> /Users/LocalUser/workspace/YourApp

Then, there typing `subl Gemfile` would work

first type `pwd` in your command terminal and check where are you right now

also if you're running it from there, then try following link solution

- https://danlimerick.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/git-for-windows-tip-opening-sublime-text-from-bash/

Comment: Hi, I have tried but sill getting the sh.exe": subl: command not found

Comment: could you try $PATH command and check if `/usr/local/bin` is there or not and also which OS you're using?

Comment: Thanks Rahul for the response. $PATH> command not found. /usr/local/bin>no such directory. I'm using Windows 7, 32-bit